# ASP.Net Core Yeoman Template issue on Mac

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, webpack, single-page-application, yeoman

I'm trying to run my asp.net core app created by aspnetcore-spa Yeoman template. The project works on windows but on Mac I have the same code and

`dotnet build
dotnet run`

are done successfully. But once I send a request to the http://localhost:5000 it returns error and logs these details in server side: 

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]`

```
An unhandled exception has occurred: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/FrontEnd/MyCompany_App/MyCompany_App/MyCompanyCore/src/MyCompany.Web/ClientApp/dist/main-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at findBootModule (/Users/FrontEnd/MyCompany_App/MyCompany_App/MyCompanyCore/src/MyCompany.Web/node_modules/aspnet-prerendering/Prerendering.js:98:24)
    at findBootFunc (/Users/FrontEnd/MyCompany_App/MyCompany_App/MyCompanyCore/src/MyCompany.Web/node_modules/aspnet-prerendering/Prerendering.js:103:5)
    at renderToString (/Users/FrontEnd/MyCompany_App/MyCompany_App/MyCompanyCore/src/MyCompany.Web/node_modules/aspnet-prerendering/Prerendering.js:10:5)
    at module.exports.renderToString (/private/var/folders/tc/yprt56j93930n80b9g_c6_nc0000gp/T/tmpiaBWzk.tmp:19:46)
    at /private/var/folders/tc/yprt56j93930n80b9g_c6_nc0000gp/T/tmp8l8hSj.tmp:113:19
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/tc/yprt56j93930n80b9g_c6_nc0000gp/T/tmp8l8hSj.tmp:132:38)

System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Cannot find module /Users/FrontEnd/MyCompany_App/MyCompany_App/MyCompanyCore/src/MyCompany.Web/ClientApp/dist/main-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at findBootModule (/Users/FrontEnd/MyCompany_App/MyCompany_App/MyCompanyCore/src/MyCompany.Web/node_modules/aspnet-prerendering/Prerendering.js:98:24)
    at findBootFunc (/Users/FrontEnd/MyCompany_App/MyCompany_App/MyCompanyCore/src/MyCompany.Web/node_modules/aspnet-prerendering/Prerendering.js:103:5)
    at renderToString (/Users/FrontEnd/MyCompany_App/MyCompany_App/MyCompanyCore/src/MyCompany.Web/node_modules/aspnet-prerendering/Prerendering.js:10:5)
    at module.exports.renderToString (/private/var/folders/tc/yprt56j93930n80b9g_c6_nc0000gp/T/tmpiaBWzk.tmp:19:46)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue took me some time to realize I didn't run webpack, so give it a go. In the project folder just run :

`webpack`

and then run your app:

`dotnet run`

and by the way the default hosting environment is production, just run this command to set it to develpment so that you can get your webpack's hot module replacement feature work.

`export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
dotnet run`